# Xcode 7.1 beta: Content Of File Error

Tags: swift, xcode6, text-files, xcode7.1beta

I had just finished the final touches to my swift app. But after upgrading to Beta 7 its giving me errors for the 'ContentOfFile' String. can anyone help me understand how I can go about fixing this please?

here's what i've got ATM.

```
//Reads the Text File
    if var path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Chapters", ofType: "txt"){

        //Reads the Text File into one Huge String
        var data = String(contentsOfFile:path, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: nil)

            //sets String content of the Text File as an Array. With each string start at \n (new line)
            if var content = (data){

                //from the mass string of data from the text file, Each chapter content is seperated by #
                var Chapters: [String] = content.componentsSeparatedByString("@")

                //without removing index in the beginning there will be an extra element printed in the array.
                Chapters.removeAtIndex(0)
```

**Error Message:** Cannot invoke initializer for type 'String' with an argument list of type '(contentsOfFile: String, encoding: UInt, error: NilLiteralConvertible)'

Comment: Xcode 6 beta 7 Are you serious ?

Comment: Hahaha my bad. that was a typo

Comment: You should download Xcode 7 GM

Comment: You need to implement do try catch and delete the last parameter (error)

Comment: tried it. didn't work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89753/discussion-between-bananab-and-leo-dabus).

Comment: for chapter in chapters.componentsSeparatedByString("^") { ... // access each chapter here }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement do try catch error handling. Try like this:

edit/update:

**Swift 3** or later

```
if let fileURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Chapters", withExtension: "txt") {
    do {
        let string = try String(contentsOf: fileURL, encoding: .utf8)
        var chapters = string.components(separatedBy: "@")
        chapters.removeFirst()
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```